# Proof of Markovnikov's Rule

Tags: organic-chemistry

Is there a proof for Markovnikov's Rule? Specifically, why does the H bond to the carbon with the most hydrogen atoms already bonded to it?

Comment: Please see [Electrophilic Addition to Unsymmetrical Alkenes on Chemguide](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/mechanisms/eladd/unsymprob.html)

Answer (score 5):

In most reactions that follow markovnikov's rule, a carbocation is formed and rearranged such that it is stabilised to the maximum extent .

[image]

The stability usually comes from the inductive effect, that is the electron releasing methyl groups that lead to a better charge distributed system. More is the number of such methyl groups surrounding the carbocation, more will be the stability and more such intermediates will be formed. These stable intermediates will be attacked by the negative reagent. This justifies the Markonikov's rule (at least in cases where carbocations are formed).

**Note:** This only applies to reactions such as acid catalysed hydration, action of halogen acids on alkenes, etc. In some reactions such as oxymercuration-demercuration no carbocation is formed but it still follows Markonikov's rule and uses a different reaction mechanism.